# Asp.net bundling and minification error when vendor minified file is added to solution

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have an asp.net MVC solution where I have the following bundle registered in App_Start\Bundle.Config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Bundle/MyNewBundle").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/lib/angularjs/angular.js"
));
```

For clarity I have removed other scripts. The solution only contains the unminified angularJS file.

My web.config has compilation to debug = false.

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
```

So when I navigate to my web project path to check the bundle i.e. http://myproj/Bundle/MyNewBundle

I see the minified contents, all good as expected.

However, I want to use the vendor supplied angular.min.js, so I have now added that to my solution in the same folder as the original angular.js.

Now when I navigate to my bundle (having rebuilt) I see the following comment at the top of the script telling me that minification has failed:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(180,448-455): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break a
*/
```

I am confused as to why the minification process is even running at this point - my understanding from the following link [Microsoft Docs - Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) is that the .min.js file should be used as per:.

> The bundling framework follows several common conventions such as:
>   **Selecting ".min" file for release when "FileX.min.js" and "FileX.js" exist**.
>   Selecting the non ".min" version for debug.
>   Ignoring "-vsdoc" files (such as jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js), which are used only by IntelliSense.

Can anyone explain why this is breaking?

Comment: Refer [this issue](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/252)

Comment: I saw that. How do I upgrade? I'm not using that extension in my IDE. From the Microsoft link I posted, why does the base framework not behave as they describe? I'm not expecting minification to happen when I have provided a minified file also.

Comment: I don't know. And I have seen this raised a few time (e.g. [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/mvc-bundling-minification-failure-for-kendo-js-css) and [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1512)). I'm not sure if the bundling framework is trying to minimize it further, or its just validating, but it sounds like a bug (perhaps you could raise an issue)